# Create hyperlink in visualforce page that redirects to corresponding create contact page for account

Tags: visualforce, redirect, hyperlink

If I launch a visualforce page called 'My New Opportunity' from the Account page with fields like custom contact in it, I would like to create a Hyperlink with the words "Don't have a Contact?" just under/right of the custom contact field(which is a lookup). 
Clicking it should redirect to the contact creation url under that particular account. Can someone tell me how to achieve this? I am very new to visualforce and couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I managed to do it on my own.

I first created a formula field on Account that returns the url of contact based on Account ID:

```
HYPERLINK("https://csxx.salesforce.com/003/e?retURL=%2F001500000xxxxem&accid="&Id&"&RecordType=0125xxxx000E7ay&ent=Contact","Click Here!")
```

Then I added this line to VF Page:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Account.Hyperlink_for_Contact__c}" escape="false"/>
```

It isn't exactly what I wanted to achieve but if fulfills my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pageblocksection item

```
<apex:pageBlocksectionitem>
  <apex:outlabel value="Your label" />
  <apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!ur Lookup Field}" />
    <apex:outputLink value="/newpage">Don't have a Contact?</apex:outputLink>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageblocksectionitem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the `AccountId` in your **My New opportunity** VF page, you can take things forward by taking a hint by creating a contact from within the standard Account page. It gives you a url like the one below:

`https://[intance/domain].salesforce.com/003/e?returl=%2F001i000000KtOhD&accid=001i000000KtOhD&RecordType=012i000000165fx&ent=Contact`

The above URL is from my org and it uses a `RecordType` to create specific contact. You can ignore that and use a similar URL and dynamic AccountId, to create complete URL for the creation of new contact.

Comment: Looked at your solution after I solved it myself. Thanks for the help.